# Use htaccess to change query parameter to iOS app-specific deep-link

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to do the following:

user visits URL with query parameter: http://www.example.com/?invite=1234

I then want them to be deep linked into the app on their iOS device, so they go to: app_name://1234

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in my .htaccess file?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

> RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

> RewriteRule    ^invite/(.*)/$    app_name://$1    [NC,L]

Comment: RewriteRule matches on the path component of the URL only, if you want to check anything in the query string, you need to do that with a RewriteCond.

Comment: (Not sure apache will “understand” pseudo protocols like `app_name://` correctly though here, you’d have to test if trying to redirect there using mod_rewrite works in general. A client-side redirect via JavaScript might be more successful, I think.)

Comment: Thank you CBroe.  Can you please send me an example code for RewriteCond or Javascript to achieve what I need?   I imagine it's only a few lines of code easily written but I am having trouble finding anything online. Thanks again.